# Wie nennt man ein Fahrrad mit elektrischem Motor?

Tags: usage, single-word-request

Ich kenne verschiedene Begriffe, wie "Elektrofahrrad", "Pedelec" oder "E-bike". Welcher Begriff ist gebräuchlich und allgemein akzeptiert?

Comment: Interessant, [wikipedia zu Pedelec](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedelec) - hatte ich noch nie gehört.

Comment: Ich vermute, dass es beio der Gebräuchlichkeit der Begriffe regionale Unterschiede geben könnte, deshalb wäre es ev. hilfreich zu wissen, für welche Anwendung/Zielgruppe der Begriff gesucht wird.

Comment: Summfiets, E-Velo, …

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die Fragestellung geht vermutlich von der Annahme aus, dass die Begriffe synonym und austauschbar seien. Es gibt jedoch eine gesetzlich relevante Definition der verschiedenen Typen der Elektroräder, die daher beachtet werden sollte:

Elektroräder (bzw. Elektrofahrräder) werden in

- Pedelecs (juristisch wie Fahrrad, bis maximal 250 Watt, Pedalkraftunterstützung bis 25 km/h)
- Schnelle Pedelecs (S-Pedelecs, Kleinkrafträder, bis maximal 500 Watt, bis 45 km/h) und
- E-Bikes (ähnlich Elektromofa, fährt also auch ohne in die Pedale zu treten, bis 500 Watt, bis 20 km/h)

unterschieden. Da der Marktanteil der klassischen Pedelecs der weitaus größte ist, sollte dieser Begriff eigentlich auch der Verbreitetste sein. Der Begriff E-Bike ist jedoch verständlicher und einprägsamer, so dass man bisweilen auch vorfindet, dass die Begriffe E-Bike und S-Pedelec gleichgesetzt oder E-Bike als Oberbegriff verwendet wird.

Siehe auch [adfc.de](http://www.adfc.de/pedelecs/elektrorad-typen/elektrorad-typen) oder [focus.de](http://www.focus.de/finanzen/recht/tid-32565/pedelecs-s-pedelecs-und-e-bikes-freizeittrend-elektro-raeder-darauf-muessen-sie-achten-pedelec-s-pedelec-und-e-bike-wo-ist-der-unterschied_aid_1054755.html) oder [gopedelec.at](http://www.gopedelec.at/gopedelec-at/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=135&Itemid=81)

Comment: Siehe dazu aber den Hinweis bei [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedelec#Begriffliche_Entwicklung): "Landläufig wird diese Definition oft nicht angewendet. Einerseits bezeichnen immer mehr Händler ihre Pedelecs als E-Bikes. Nicht zuletzt deshalb, weil E-Bikes im eigentlichen Sinne ... in Europa kaum verkauft werden. Andererseits haben Pedelecs vermehrt auch Anfahrhilfen, die es ermöglichen, auch ohne zu pedalieren per Drehgriff zu beschleunigen. Damit ist eine Unterscheidung der Begriffe E-Bike und Pedelec oft nicht mehr klar möglich."

Comment: @hellcode: Inwiefern beantwortet dein Posting die Frage? (»Welcher Begriff ist gebräuchlich und allgemein akzeptiert?«) Du listest nur auf welche Begriffe es gibt ohne darauf einzugehen wie gebräuchlich oder akzeptiert sie sind. Eine Liste der Begriffe hat der Fragesteller aber bereits selbst erstellt.

Comment: @hellcode: Dann solltest du vielleicht genau das (nämlich, dass die Frage von einer falschen Prämisse ausgeht) in der Antwort aus ausdrücklich ansprechen.

Comment: Die gesetzliche Unterscheidung der verschiedenen Typen ist sicherlich interessant. Allerdings kommen die Bezeichnungen „Pedelec“ und „E-Bike“, um die es in der Fragestellung geht, im Gesetzestext nicht vor.

Comment: @Loong: Danke für den Hinweis. Ich habe aber auch nicht behauptet, dass die Bezeichnungen im Gesetzestext stehen. Es sollte nur unterstreichen, dass die Definition eine gesetzliche Relevanz hat und die Begriffe daher nicht beliebig ausgetauscht werden sollten.

Answer (score 2):

Am geläufigsten dürfte wohl

> E-Bike

sein. Achte auf die richtige Schreibweise (großes B)!
Auch »Elektrofahrrad« wird jeder verstehen, wenngleich ich diesen Begriff weniger häufig wahrgenommen habe.

»Pedelec« habe ich - außer hier, in deiner Frage - noch nie gehört oder gelesen. Ohne Kontext hätte ich wohl nicht erraten, dass ein Pedelec ein Fahrrad mit Elektromotor sein soll. Ich wüsste mit dem Begriff gar nichts anzufangen.